# Modifying an arc/curved line in a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am rather new to tikz, but I have been studying it extensively lately, and I have received great help in [this question I asked here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640602/how-would-one-draw-the-following-figure-describing-a-wave-in-tikz?noredirect=1#comment1596625_640602). I have written the code below

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=2]
\coordinate (A) at (0,3);
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (3,0);
\coordinate (D) at (3,3);

\coordinate (E) at (0,2);
\coordinate (F) at (3,2);

\draw[fill=teal] (E) .. controls (1.5,2.75) and (1.5,2.75) .. (F) -- 
(C) 
-- 
(B) 
-- (E);

\draw (A) -- (E);
\draw (D) -- (F);

\draw[color=blue] (E) .. controls (1.5,2.75) and (1.5,2.75) .. (F) ;


\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces the figure on the left, whereas I seek the one on the right in what appears below

[image: curves]

I do not care about the colors, nor the length and width of the outer frame/box. What I do care about is the shape of the arc/curve on top. In the left figure, the curve seems to be curved at the beginning and end, whereas in the right figure, the top curve/arc is flatter near the left and right endpoints (I have highlighted the specified areas of concern in red). I have tried modifying my control points but that did not seem to work. Can this be done with tikz using control points, or do I need something else entirely? I thank all helpers and would appreciate any and all help on this.

Comment: You'll need to draw it as two bezier curves, so you'll need a middle point on the curve, maybe `G` at `(1.5,2.5)`, then something like `(E) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (G) .. controls +(1,0) and +(-1,0) .. (F)`.  Experiment a bit with the numbers to get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to adjust curves like this is to use `out=` and `in=` in the `to` command:

`\draw (E) to[out=0, in=180] (G)` will make the outgoing angle 0 (to the east) from `(E)` and the incoming angle 180 (from the west) into `(G)`. So place the coordinate `(G)` where you want, say at `(1.5,2.5)`.

[image]

You can adjust the `looseness` of the arc by adding `looseness=.8` (or whatever factor appeals to you) to the `\draw` options: `\draw[fill=teal, looseness=.8]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=2]
\coordinate (A) at (0,3);
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (3,0);
\coordinate (D) at (3,3);

\coordinate (E) at (0,2);
\coordinate (F) at (3,2);
\coordinate (G) at (1.5,2.5);

\draw[fill=teal] (E) to[out=0, in=180] (G) to[out=0, in=180] (F) -- (C) -- (B) -- cycle;

\draw (A) -- (E);
\draw (D) -- (F);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```